# Paste a range based on a filled column

Tags: excel, vba

How can I paste a copied range (m2:bm6) to all lines that have some info on column L from cell M7

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
Range("M2:BM6").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("M7").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("m7:M" & Range("l" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: The range "M2:BM6" consists of 53 columns and 5 rows. When pasting it, it cannot be condensed into a single column.

Comment: In this case, i dont want to paste in a single column, but paste the info from this 5 rows and 53 columns on the lines below, as i have on this copied range

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is what r u looking for.

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim rRng As Range, cnt As Long
    Set rRng = Range("M2:BM6")
    cnt = 1
    For i = 7 To Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        If Len(Trim(Cells(i, "L"))) > 0 Then
            rRng.Rows(cnt).Copy Cells(i, "M")
            cnt = cnt + 1
            If cnt > rRng.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @taller but it extended the formula only for next 5 lines and not for all the lines with data in L, any idea?

Comment: only for information, i have on this sheet about 570K lines in buckets of 5 and i need to paste the first info for each one of these buckets, i try to find some loop code, but i didn't have success

Comment: I would suggest that you upload a screen snapshot and give the detail of your goal.